# HTML link HTML code inside (for toolbar across multiple pages)

Tags: html, import

I would like to be able to use something similar to a stylesheet but with HTML so that I only have to edit one set of code to edit the toolbar's HTML code across multiple pages. Is there a way to use a  tag or something to import HTML code into the body section,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of include() in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928331/equivalent-of-include-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to type out your navigation bar / header in a html page, save it has header.php and then in all of your other pages (for example index page), type in

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

at the beginning to grab the header. Make sure the header.php is in the same folder as your other files (for example index.php)..

Let me know if it does or doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make sure your server has PHP installed, then use include

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include "toolbar.html";
?>
</body>
</html>
```