# Create navigation Bar From Different HTML, Link to Main HTML

Tags: html, indexing

i just wanted to find out is it posible to make a navigation bar or image slide from a different html & css and link it to the main index.html?

if it is possible how to do it, or must it be done as a script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of include() in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928331/equivalent-of-include-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this with both Javascript/jQuery and PHP.  It's also possible to do this with an iframe, but iframes are honestly used to load a new web page within your site and they are hardly ever used, plus HTML5 is going to depreciate them once it becomes standard.  So to answer your question, yes, it's something that needs to be done with a scripting language