# Reuse html in different pages

Tags: html, amazon-s3, reusability

This is my website, https://unrealcousinzzz.com/.

I made it in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  I cannot use PHP or anything like that right now because I am hosting it in AWS S3, because lightsail is too expensive for me.  On each page in my website, I use the same HTML code. For example, every page has code for my navbar, and code google AdSense.

If I want to change these, I would have to do it on every page right now.  Is there a way to make a file that other HTML pages will read, and use that where it is placed in that page?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928331/equivalent-of-include-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for me google tag manager is good.  I can add custom html, and it goes onto all of my pages.

Answer (score 0):

HTML itself doesn't have any sort of templating, but there are alternatives.

Use something on your dev machine to compile your HTML for you.  I use a Node.js script and a [JavaScript template engine](http://olado.github.io/doT/) for this.  Basically, I write out my templates, run the script which generates the HTML, and then I upload it to the S3 bucket.

It doesn't have to be done with Node.  You could use PHP with this same method.  Or, a Bash script for that matter.